# Build process xaml file cannot find Workspace

Tags: xaml, azure, tfs

I am attempting to follow the tutorial for CI with Azure and a Team Foundation Build Server [located here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery/), but am running into an issue with the configuration of the build configuration template XAML file, in Step 5. In trying to configure a new `ConvertWorkSpaceItem`, and add it to the modified build template TFS provides (TfvsTemplate.12.xaml) so that a custom script can be run on a TFS build agent, I attempt to set the property Workspace = "Workspace", but am given a compiler error: *'Workspace' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.*

[image: here is the snippet in question of my diagram.]

I've done some troubleshooting already, and the errors that have happened to others -- not scoping the `CreateWorkSpaceItem`, or using the wrong version of TFS or Visual Studio -- do not seem to be issues. I placed the logic correctly inside the "Run on Agent" block, so the scope should be right, and Visual Studio and my TFS Server are both running 2013. My only thought is that the instructions are out of date, and there is some other step that needs to be taken that I am missing. Any ideas?

EDIT:
[Here are the parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzV3p.jpg) for the first failed convert item. The second failed Convert item is similar. The Input and Result variables are parameters defined by me for the workflow as part of the instructions for the tutorial. The error displayed is: "Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Workspace". 'Workspace' is a type and cannot be used as an expression."

Comment: can you add the actual error being displayed by the blue and white exclamation mark, and what the parameters are for the displayed activities

Comment: @JustTFS Let me know if you need more information about parameters. For reference, all these steps are performed in Step 5 of the instructions I'm following, linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok this has come up a couple of times now, for TFS 2013.

Built in variables used to be available for

> SourcesDirectory, Binaries Directory and Workspace

these are no longer available in TFS 2013 you now have to use

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables

to access these.

Getting the workspace is a little more complicated but if you assign some local variables you should be able to get the workspace object.

Declare local variables for sourcesDirectory (string) and buildDetail (IBuildDetail) and workSpace(Workspace) set their scope to the whole workflow

Create an GetEnvironmentVariable Activity and set its **Result** value to be sourcesDirectory and use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory.
[image: Get Sources Directory Value]

Repeat the same for buildDetail = WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BuildDetail

Create an assign task  for the workSpace object, set this one as
workSpace =
"[buildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.GetService().GetWorkspace(sourcesDirectory)]"

This should then give you a Workspace object to use.

note: syntax might be slightly out.

To compliment the removal of these variables MS have added a new Activity

> GetLocalPath

which may be of use to you instead

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I replaced my two ConvertWorkspaceItem components with GetLocalPath items, as suggested, and it now works like a charm. Thanks!